# How to eliminate duplicates after result set on a complex SQL situation

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 11g.  I am working on a query of multiple table joins where the results have a few duplicate values that I cant seem to eliminate.  The main table is TABLE1 where I am pulling all data.  I have to do a join within the same table to extract TYPE 1 vs 2 data to flatten it out.  Then I am doing a simple join to get some data for LOC_ID from table2.  Then the third join to get more data.  However, its within the third table that I can eliminate the duplicate by look at the column labeled INVT_PRI.  The problem is I only want to look at that column IF I have a duplicate..otherwise I never want to base my decision off of that column as it has different meanings.  Less than 10 records have this duplicate issue out of a few thousand.  Here is soem table data:

```
TABLE1                                    TABLE2
  LOC_ID  INVT_CD  CNT_CD   TYPE        LOC_ID  LOC_NAME  LOC_ADDR
  111     AA       US       1           111     PRIMUSA   123 Main
  111     BB       US       1           112     SECUSA    117 Northern
  111     11133    US       2           113     ELVUSA    222 Southern
  112     CC       US       1           114     DISTAEU   134 Elaveen
  112     11233    US       2   
  113     FF       US       1
  113     55555    US       2
  114     LL       EU       1
  114     MM       EU       1
  114     22222    EU       2

TABLE3
 LOC_ID   INVT_CD  PHS_IND  ILW_IND INVT_PRI
  111     AA        S        S      BB
  111     BB        S        S      BB
  112     CC        S        S      CC
  113     FF        S        S      Z
  114     LL        S        S      LL
  114     MM        S        S      LL
```

Here is the SQL I have so far...This gets me to the point where I have joined all the data I need except I have not taken care of these few duplicates:

```
 SELECT distinct 
   a.LOC_ID,
   a.INVT_CD PSEUDO,
   a.CNT_CD,
   c.LOC_NAME,
   c.LOC_ADDR,
   b.INVT_CD DOMAIN,
   d.PHS_IND,
   d.ILW_IND,
   d.INVT_PRI
 FROM TABLE1 a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 b ON a.LOC_ID = b.LOC_ID AND TYPE = 2
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 c ON c.LOC_ID = a.LOC_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 d ON d.LOC_ID = a.LOC_ID
 WHERE a.TYPE = 1;
```

Results look something like:

```
 LOC_ID  PSEUDO   CNT_CD   LOC_NAME  LOC_ADDR        DOMAIN   PHS_IND  ILW_IND  INVT_PRI
  111    AA       US       PRIMUSA   123 Main        11133    S         S        BB
  111    BB       US       PRIMUSA   123 Main        11133    S         S        BB
  112    CC       US       SECUSA    117 Northern    11233    S         S        CC
  113    FF       US       ELVUSA    222 Southern    55555    S         S        Z
  114    LL       EU       DISTAEU   134 Elaveen     22222    S         S        LL
  114    MM       EU       DISTAEU   134 Elaveen     22222    S         S        LL
```

But, I would like to remove the duplicate LOC_IDs from the result and keep the row where the PSEUDO = INVT_PRI and discard the other row.  As I mentioned, I cannot always use INVT_PRI for this purpose...only when I detect the duplicates.

I appreciate your time and help if you know an easy solution for this without going to a procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a prioritization, which you can do with `row_number()`.  For convenience, I'll put your query in a CTE:

```
with t as (
      SELECT a.LOC_ID, a.INVT_CD PSEUDO, a.CNT_CD, c.LOC_NAME, c.LOC_ADDR,
             b.INVT_CD DOMAIN, d.PHS_IND, d.ILW_IND, d.INVT_PRI
      FROM TABLE1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN
           TABLE1 b
           ON a.LOC_ID = b.LOC_ID AND TYPE = 2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
           TABLE2 c
           ON c.LOC_ID = a.LOC_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
           TABLE3 d
           ON d.LOC_ID = a.LOC_ID
      WHERE a.TYPE = 1
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by loc_id
                                order by (case when PSEUDO = INVT_PRI then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will keep one row for each `loc_id`.  By preference, it will be the one where these two values match.  If none match, then, it will choose another row.

Answer (score 1):

**Fiddle test:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc31a5/5/0

```
with sub as
 (SELECT distinct a.LOC_ID,
                  a.INVT_CD  PSEUDO,
                  a.CNT_CD,
                  c.LOC_NAME,
                  c.LOC_ADDR,
                  b.INVT_CD  DOMAIN,
                  d.PHS_IND,
                  d.ILW_IND,
                  d.INVT_PRI
    FROM TABLE1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 b
      ON a.LOC_ID = b.LOC_ID
     AND b.TYPE = 2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 c
      ON c.LOC_ID = a.LOC_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 d
      ON d.LOC_ID = a.LOC_ID
   WHERE a.TYPE = 1),
dup as
 (select loc_id from sub group by loc_id having count(*) > 1)
select sub.*
  from sub
  left join dup
    on sub.loc_id = dup.loc_id
 where (sub.pseudo = sub.invt_pri and dup.loc_id is not null)
    or dup.loc_id is null
 order by sub.loc_id
```